# Getting an error related to observable Angular2

Tags: angular

I am trying to run my angular application using **dotnet watch run** command but I am getting the following error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: Error:
>   Cannot find module "rxjs/Observable" at webpackMissingModule
>   (C:\MyProject\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:10340:91) at
>   module.exports.Object.setPrototypeOf.**proto**
>   (C:\MyProject\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:10340:183)

Here's my package.json class:

```
{
  "name": "MyProject",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/http": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "4.2.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
    "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.3",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.10",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^12.0.0",
    "angular-datatables": "^5.0.0",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.6.0",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.16",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.16",
    "json-stringify-safe": "^5.0.1",
    "ng2-toasty": "^4.0.3",
    "raven-js": "^3.25.0"
  }
}
```

I am pretty new to Angular and have already reviewed this link and tried all the solutions given here but NON worked out for me: 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4756

Comment: You have a lot of things in dev-dependencies, which should actually be in dependencies. Any idea why?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea.

Comment: Try copying the items which you want in the vendor.js to dependencies, that includes angular packages, rxjs, jQuery etc.

Comment: devDependencies are packages that help to bundle, validate, test.. your code. dependencies are the packages that will be packaged and used in your application.